# How to add a frame to UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have an app that I a writing that have 3 buttons with a background image for each button.
When the user touch one of the buttons I want that a green frame will appear around the the button for a 2 seconds and then disappear.

I know the I can build 2 separate images with and without the frame around the image but this will cause double the amount of files.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add a border to any UIView (UIButton is a subclass of UIView) by accessing properties of the CALayer in the view:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius  = 6;   // if you want rounded corners    
button.layer.borderWidth   = 2;
button.layer.borderColor   = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

You will need to import QuartzCore.h in the file to be able to reference the layer declarations:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

You can turn on the border in response to the button's touch down (or up) event and then turn it off (borderWidth=0) with a timer.

Comment: Hi progrmr, I did what you said but in the simulator I dont see the green frame at all. Do you know y?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is a way to make it the way you want.

you have to make just two image, one when the button is not selected and the other when it's selected.